# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gTTs (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for gTTs

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-text-to-speech

I have been working on trying to code a AI assistant in python. But when i try to install gTTs or basically anything, it would say, Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gTTs (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for gTTs. I have tried pip install, sudo pip install, and other things i cannot remember. If somone could help me with this issue, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I believe the package [is called gTTS](http://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and not gTTs. Could it be that's the source of your problem?

Comment: That said the same thing as if i put in gTTs

Comment: Do you happen to be on OS X? Check out [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/41253#issuecomment-117830571) where someone had a similar problem and resolved it. Scroll down to where people are saying it worked for them and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: I am relatively new to coding so i don't really know what they are talking about. If you could give me some clarification, that would be great!

Comment: Did you look for the files in [this post](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/41253#issuecomment-117830571) on your machine? I think what they're saying is sometimes you can have more than one of them, and one might be out of date and supercede the other one, meaning your pip will be unable to properly validate TLS certificates and you'll get the error you're reporting.

Comment: Using the finder app on my macbook, i was not able to find any of the files listed. I still don't know for sure because i don't know if i was searching correctly. Let me know how to search for files of a mac. Thanks!

Comment: Try opening a terminal and using `cd /etc/ssl/certs/` for instance to change into the directory, then run `ls` to see what files are there.

Comment: When i copy cd/etc/ssl/certs and paste it into terminal, it just says, "cd/etc/ssl/certs: No such file or directory"

Comment: Go through the list of in that post. Make sure you have a space between cd and the directory you're trying to go into, as what you've copied here has no space. `cd` is a command that changes your current directory.

Comment: in terminal, added a space between them and pressed enter. I got nothing so i typed in ls and got Applications   etc
Library    home
Network    installer.failurerequests
System    net
Users    private
Volumes    sbin
bin    tmp
cores    usr
dev    var

Comment: Just go through the different folders using `ls` and look for each of those files listed. If you find some in `/etc/`, that thread is suggesting to rename them and then see if it fixes your `pip` not working. Having a back and forth like this in the comments is really not ideal so please look in the other thread and try what it says there, and if you need help doing a certain thing then use Google before coming here.

Answer (score -1):

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gTTs (from
versions: ) No matching distribution found for gTTs

**To solve the issue, the user first set the environment variables .
copy the python location ,and also copy the python scripts location
and add the both location in system variables and user variables**

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained: the root cause of the problem and how taking these steps would solve it.  It could also specify which environment variables should be set, and to what values.  And whether taking these steps would have any side effects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).